# UWP - Unable to load DLL 'realm-wrappers'

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms, realm

I have a Xamarin/Realm app that I created using Visual Studio 2017 on Win10. It targets iOS, Android and UWP. I'm trying to build this solution on Windows and macOS.

I added Realm in macOS and successfully tested my app on Android and iOS. Then when I moved back to my windows machine. It's currently targetting UWP. When I run the app on my Local Machine, I see the following runtime exception:

```
System.TypeInitializationException occurred
  HResult=0x80131534
  Message=The type initializer for 'Realms.Realm' threw an exception.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
   at Realms.Realm.GetInstance(RealmConfigurationBase config)
   at MouseDroid.MainPageViewModel..ctor() in C:\Users\hmurphy\Documents\Pittsh\Projects\mouse_droid\MouseDroid\MainPageViewModel.cs:line 20
   at MouseDroid.MainPage..ctor() in C:\Users\hmurphy\Documents\Pittsh\Projects\mouse_droid\MouseDroid\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 28
   at MouseDroid.App..ctor() in C:\Users\hmurphy\Documents\Pittsh\Projects\mouse_droid\MouseDroid\App.xaml.cs:line 17
   at MouseDroid.UWP.MainPage..ctor() in C:\Users\hmurphy\Documents\Pittsh\Projects\mouse_droid\MouseDroid.UWP\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 24
   at MouseDroid.UWP.MouseDroid_UWP_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider.Activate_4_MainPage() in C:\Users\hmurphy\Documents\Pittsh\Projects\mouse_droid\MouseDroid.UWP\obj\x64\Debug\XamlTypeInfo.g.cs:line 207
   at MouseDroid.UWP.MouseDroid_UWP_XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.ActivateInstance() in C:\Users\hmurphy\Documents\Pittsh\Projects\mouse_droid\MouseDroid.UWP\obj\x64\Debug\XamlTypeInfo.g.cs:line 429

Inner Exception 1:
DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'realm-wrappers': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

This happens inside my `MainPageViewModel` with the call to `GetInstance`:

```
public class MainPageViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Package> Packages { get; private set; }

    public INavigation Navigation { get; set; }

    private Realm _realm;

    public MainPageViewModel() 
    {
        _realm = Realm.GetInstance();

        Packages = _realm.All<Package>();
    }
}
```

I'm using 1.5.0. According to this [commit](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/commit/daf3077f4fc6f3d8ad9bfd80f190f52df0e2b6a5), it seems like this shouldn't be an issue.

My configuration is using x86 for UWP. UWP is set to build and deploy. I have re-built my solution, just in case `FodyWeaver` objects were not generated properly. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update Oct '17: As of Realm 2.0.0, syncing for UWP is fully supported and upgrading to the latest version should solve the issue.

---

For people who want to stick with pre-2.0, here's the previous answer:

You should remove the [Realm](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Realm/) package on UWP and instead use [Realm.Database](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Realm.Database) one. The reason you're getting this error is that the Realm package includes API related to syncing, which is [not yet supported on UWP/Windows](https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/#limitations-on-windows-desktop-or-uwp).

Comment: Thank God. I thought I was going nuts

Comment: Though now I'm getting the following error - `Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)`

Comment: Never mind, this was happening because I was fiddling with an `{x:Bind}` in my xaml. Not related to Realm like I had thought